# sortBy is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, rdd, sbt-assembly

Hello~ I'm interested in SPARK.
I use this below code in spark-shell.

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(2,3,4), Array(1,2,1))
res6: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Int]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:26

data.map(x => (x(d), 1)).reduceByKey((x,y) => x + y).sortBy(_._1)
res9: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,2), (2,1))
```

It work. But, if I use this command using sbt assembly, It's not worked.

The error message is

> [error] value sortBy is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)]
>
> [error]       data.map(x => (x(d), 1)).reduceByKey((x,y) => x + y).**sortBy(_._1)** <= here is the problem.

my build.sbt code is

```
import AssemblyKeys._

assemblySettings

name := "buc"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.0.0" % "provided"
```

Is there something problem?

Comment: what version of spark are you using ?

Comment: I'm using spark version 2.0.0.
(spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7)

Comment: yet you are loading spark-mllib_2.10 version 1.0.0. Does it make sense to you know ?

Comment: actually.. I don't know well this...
should I change to spark-mllib_2.10 version 2.0.0.??

Comment: plus, my plugins.sbt code is
`addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")`.
Is it Ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you are using `spark 1.0.0`, and if you read the documentation you won't find any `sortBy` method in the [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) class. So,you should update from `1.0.x` to `2.0.x`.

On other hand, the `spark-mllib` dependency is used to get the Spark MLlib library and that's not what you need. You need to get the dependency for `spark-core` :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.0.0" % "provided"
```

Comment: Ok~! upvote !!
could you answer one more question if you don't mind?
If I want to use MLlib with spark-core_2.10, then the code is `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % spark-mllib_2.10 % "2.0.0" % "provided"` ?

Comment: Thank you very much!
have a nice day~